# Iterate matrix of vectors using c++ with auto range and structured binding?

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I want to do something like this:

```
vector<vector<int>>& matrix; -> [[1, 1], [2, 2]]

for (auto [a, b] : matrix) {
    ...
}
```

This won't compile for me. Is this the correct way to do this? If not why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above approach is only valid for iterating over the map in C++. If d is unordered map then it can be iterated through the below code

```
for(auto& [a,b] : d)
{
    count<< "First" << a.first << "Second" << a.second <<endl;
}
```

To iterate over the vector> matrix as in this case the below code can be used,

```
vector<vector<int>> mat = { {1,1},{2,2} };
for (auto& a : mat) {
  for (auto& b : a) {
    cout << b << " ";
  }
  cout <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Not only map, but any container that got a pair or an equivalent element. I.e. the bind list must correspond to a type jnown during compilation. That's why it cannot be used to bind two elements of vector

Answer (score 1):

You can use structured binding only for storage, location of which can be determined at compile time, i.e. bind it to array or class-like storage. Vector's data storage is dynamic, you can't bind to its content , comprising of adjacent elements.
You can bind that list to members of existing type, e.g. if vector contains a pair, a tuple or any similar structure.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::tuple<int,int, std::string>> 
                            v  = {{1,3,"aa"},{3,5,"bb"}};
    
   for(auto& [a,b,s] : v)
   {
       std::cout << a << b << s << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```